# Checking the availability of the coach

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

Coach Table:

[image]

Tour Table:

[image]

Create a query which shows list of coach available for given dates
I have stuck on this query and i have no idea how to proceed:

```
SELECT
    c.coachID,
    c.coachNo
FROM 
    Tour t 
    inner join Coach c 
        on t.coachID=c.coachID 
WHERE 
    '10/01/2016' BETWEEN startDate AND (DATEADD(DAY,tourDuration,startDate))
```

the output:

```
coachID|coachNo
1      |WKS5623
```

Comment: show us what you tried?

Comment: i would like to show the coach id and coachNo which are available on the specific date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the available coaches in following way:

1. Find out which coaches are in tour now

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   CoachID 
FROM
   Tour 
WHERE
   '10/01/2016' BETWEEN startDate AND 
   (DATEADD(DAY, tourDuration, startDate))
```

2. Get those coaches who are not in the list of coaches are in tour now

```
SELECT
   CoachId,
   CoachNo 
FROM
   Coach 
WHERE
   CoachId NOT IN 
   (SELECT DISTINCT
         CoachID 
      FROM
         Tour 
      WHERE
         '10/01/2016' BETWEEN startDate AND 
         (DATEADD(DAY, tourDuration, startDate)))
```